# Adding hundreds of fields to a content type in Drupal 6

Tags: entities

I have over a hundred fields to be added.

How can I use CSV or SQL statement to add these fields in Drupal? Is there any module to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Do you need to add hundreds of fields to one or more content types? Or do you want to import hundreds of values into nodes of a certain type? And which Drupal version are you using?

Comment: I want to add hundred of field to a content type. Not adding node to a content type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one time I had to do something like that (it was a Drupal 6 site) I exported the content type, edited the export manually (lots of copy-paste and search-replace) and imported it back into my site.

That said, a content type with hundreds of fields is going to be huge. I'm afraid that it's going to be a nightmare for your editors, terrible to maintain, and it might hurt performance as well. If I ever needed a content type with hundreds of fields, I would stop right there and start re-thinking my site architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, how can I export a content type?

Comment: I can't tell you, because you still didn't mention which Drupal version you're using.

Comment: Sorry for that, I am using Drupal 6

Comment: Use the content copy module that ships with CCK.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module, or maybe [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush).